# Why can't I restore the DB from an SQL dump in PostgreSQL 9.4 (problem with dblink)?

Tags: restore, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump, dblink

I have created a dump of a DB using:

```
pg_dump db_name > db_dump.sql
```

and proceed to restore it with:

```
psql --single-transaction db_name < db_dump.sql
```

Prior to attempting to restore the DB, I create the DB as:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS db_name;
CREATE DATABASE db_name;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE db_name TO db_user;
```

Also, prior to creating the DB `db_name` I add the extension `dblink` to the DB `template1` as the user `postgres` as per:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
```

The command `\df+` executed in the DB `db_name` shows:

```
 List of functions
 Schema |  Name  | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  | Security | Volatility |  Owner   |... 
--------+--------+------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+------------+----------+---
 public | dblink | SETOF record     | text                | normal | invoker  | volatile   | postgres |...
 public | dblink | SETOF record     | text, boolean       | normal | invoker  | volatile   | postgres |...
 public | dblink | SETOF record     | text, text          | normal | invoker  | volatile   | postgres |...
 public | dblink | SETOF record     | text, text, boolean | normal | invoker  | volatile   | postgres |...
```

When I go to execute `psql --single-transaction db_name < db_dump.sql` I see the following error message:

```
ERROR:  function dblink(text, text) does not exist
```

The output from `\df+` tells me that the extension has been added though.

**Why is this happening? What have I missed?**

Comment: Maybe the `dblink` module was installed into a different schema in the source database. Can you show us the complete statement that fails from the input file? Also check the source file for `set search_path` or `set schema` statements prior to the failing statement

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @a_horse_with_no_name helped me solve the issue i.e., the extension was not installed in the right schema when attempting to restore the DB. When moved to the right schema the restore finished with no errors.